# MySQL isn't finding a row just for one username but it exists?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP/MySQL script for logging in, and it works fine for other people, but it doesn't work for my username and it tells me that no account was found with that username. I even tried creating a new row in the users table in the database and it logged in fine with that, just doesn't work with my name for some reason.

```
 if($submit)
   {
        if($username && $password)
        {
            $passhash = strtoupper(hash("whirlpool", $password));

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT name, password FROM users WHERE name = '$username'");

            if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 1)
            {
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                {
                    $dbusername = $row['name'];
                    $dbpassword = $row['password'];
                    if($username == $dbusername && $passhash == $dbpassword)
                    {
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $dbusername;
                        echo header('location: profile.php');
                    }
                    else echo "The password you entered was incorrect.";
                }
            }
            else echo "No account was found with that name!";
        }
        else echo "You must enter your name and password!";
    }
```

It just echos "No account was found with that name!".

This only started happening when I uploaded the website to a web host, it worked fine locally.

Comment: Can you give examples of a username that works and one that doesn't?

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). They are not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Are you sure your username doesn't appear twice in the database?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is in quotes, if you use simple quotes it takes the variable as literal.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name, password FROM users WHERE name = '".$username".'");
```

Anyway, i recomend you to be carefull with all variables that are used inside your SQL to avoid sql injection.